# display machine IP in the URL and run the defined web services

Tags: c#, java, asp.net

I have started learning web services. I got the entire concept. Till now I'm running through `localhost:1234/services.asmx`. It's working. But now I want to put my machine IP address instead of localhost. I'm having idea of web services. Is there any specific method to run by machine ip? plz help me. I have done lot of search. Please tel me any solution for this.

```
namespace WebService1
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to host the web service somewhere, for example in IIS

Answer (score 0):

You can configure you (so called) bindings in the web.config or the app.config.

If it's not self-hosted you have to deploy it to an IIS-Webserver before trying to access it.

Comment: means in web config i have to pass some methods then only i can access it through ip address.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your comment